# Assigning the output of a C program in unix shell script and checking the value

Tags: shell, unix

Let's say I have a C program that evaluates to either a zero or non zero integer; basically a program that evaluates to a boolean value.

I wish to write a shell script that can find out whether the C program evaluates to zero or not. I am currently trying to assign the return value of the C program to a variable in a shell script but seem to be unable to do so. I currently have;

```
#!/bin/sh
variable=/path/to/executable input1
```

I know that assigning values in shell script requires us not to have spaces, but I do not know another way around this, since running this seems to evaluate to an error since the shell interprets `input1` as a command, not an input. Is there a way I can do this?

I am also unsure as to how to check the return value of the C program. Should I just use an if statement and check if the C program evaluates to a value equal to zero or not?

Comment: BTW: the fact that the program is a [tag:c] program doesn't mean that you need to tag the question as a [tag:c] question.

Comment: Aah, I apologize. I don't go here often. Your advice is noted however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very basic

```
#!/bin/sh
variable=`/path/to/executable input1`
```

or

```
#!/bin/sh
variable=$(/path/to/executable input1)
```

and to get the return code from the program use

```
echo $?
```

Comment: Ah, it is that simple. Apologies for my noob-ness. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign with backticks or `$(...)` as shown in [iharob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983495/iharob)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35228138/3266847).

Another way is to interpret a zero return value as success and evaluate that directly (see [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)):

```
if /path/to/executable input1; then
    echo "The return value was 0"
else
    echo "The return value was not 0"
fi
```

Testing with a little dummy program that exits with 0 if fed "yes" and exits with 1 else:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$1"

if [[ $var == yes ]]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Testing:

```
$ if ./executable yes; then echo "Returns 0"; else echo "Doesn't return 0"; fi
Returns 0
$ if ./executable no; then echo "Returns 0"; else echo "Doesn't return 0"; fi
Doesn't return 0
```

<sub>If not using Bash: `if [ "$var" = "yes" ]; then`</sub>